# Keyboard shortcuts not working with a Bluetooth keyboard on the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

When using a Bluetooth keyboard to edit posts on the iOS app, some formatting shortcuts are working as expected (for example, if I type <kbd>i</kbd> from the Bluetooth keyboard, it will change to ‘*emphasized text*’). But others are just not responding.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone 10,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.3 (Build 15E216)

Answer (score 1):

Usually that happens when a key is in locked mode, means that although it is not pressed, the system considers it as pressed. For example "control"+I = italic, means that your "control" key may be bugged. Quick steps as suggestions:

1. Simply try to click once all control keys you have in your keyboard and check if it solves.
2. Restart the bluetooth keyboard
3. remove and reconnect the keyboard
4. update the apps involved
5. update firmware of the keyboard, if possible
6. update the OS, if possible
7. try another keyboard.